# Creating "nested structs" without -fms-extensions?

Tags: c, struct, c11

I have a struct with some properties:

```
struct a {
    char* id;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

I also have a struct with the same properties, but without the `id`.

```
struct b {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

I know that C11 supports anonymous structs, so I could do something like this:

```
struct a {
    char* id;
    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    }
}
```

However, if I give the inner struct a tag, it fails. Is it possible to create nested structs like this without using a non-standard compiler option like `-fms-extensions`?

Comment: Until C11 becomes commonplace, then no, you'll always be reliant on compiler-specific extensions.

Comment: Compiler options are not standard whichever way you do it, I'd use the flags it takes to make the compiler implement C11 correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the inner structure a name or a tag or both in C11 (i.e., without the use of any extension).

Without a tag and without a name, your inner structure is a C11 anonymous structure:

```
struct a {
    char* id;
    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    };
 };
```

If you give the inner anonymous structure a name, it is no longer an anonymous structure. It is a regular C89/C99/C11 structure member and you cannot access the inner structure members directly as with anonymous structures.

If you give the inner anonymous structure a tag (but still no name), it is just a C89/C99/C11 structure declaration. There is no member added and the declaration of `struct a` is the same as:

```
struct a {
    char* id;
};
```

Comment: Really? Because if I do `struct a { struct b { int a; }; };` and then do `a.a`, I get an error that struct a has no member named 'a'. Is this a compiler support problem? Or is it not allowed in C11?

Comment: @JakeKing see my edit, it is no longer an anonymous structure so it is not allowed.

Comment: @JakeKing in the C definition an anonymous structure is an inner structure with no tag and no name.

Comment: Ah, alright, got it. I'm a little confused as to *why* that isn't supported, but I realize that isn't within the scope of this question. However, I don't really want to have to refer to the inner struct's members indirectly, so I'd still rather duplicate the members anyway. I guess there's no way around it, then?

Comment: Not portably to my knowledge. But if you don't want anyway to access the inner struct members indirectly, why the need to name the struct?

Comment: I guess my terminology is wrong. I want to *tag* it, not name it.

Comment: @JakeKing if you only tag it, it is also no longer an anonymous structure but it is also not a member of the outer structure. It is just a useless declaration.